# How can we use std::tuple in conjunction with ranges

Tags: c++, range, fmt, c++23

The problem I got is I have a function that takes a variadic argument. I want to use this for `fmt` printing . The way I am trying to achieve this is by joining them.

I have my join function:

```
template <typename RANGE, typename Projection = std::identity>
inline auto join(const RANGE& range, std::string_view sep, Projection&& proj = std::identity{}) {
    auto joined = range
        | std::views::transform([&proj](const auto& element) { return std::invoke(proj, element); })
        | std::views::join_with(sep);
    return std::ranges::to<std::string>(joined);
}
```

for now ignore `std::invoke` as it is simply deducing to the identity i.e. `std::format("{}");`

If I supply a vector it works fine, however, if I got a variadic function like:

```
template<Args..>
foo(Args... args) {
       std::string goo = std::format(
        "Show me the keys: {}",
        join(args..., ",")
    );
}
```

It does not work. I also tried with `std::forward_as_tuple` to cast my `args` to a `std::tuple`, however, that did not help since operand `|` is not supported by `std::tuple`.

I have an example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/joWfKq47f) showing the case with a `std::vector` and `std::tuple` (in conjunction with variadic arguments)

The whole example is pasted below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
#include <format>
#include <functional>

    

template <typename RANGE, typename Projection = std::identity>
inline auto join(const RANGE& range, std::string_view sep, Projection&& proj = std::identity{}) {
    auto joined = range
        | std::views::transform([&proj](const auto& element) { return std::invoke(proj, element); })
        | std::views::join_with(sep);
    return std::ranges::to<std::string>(joined);
}

template<typename... KEYS>
auto get(KEYS... keys) {
    return std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<KEYS>(keys)...);
}

int main() {
    auto tuple_range = get("bla", "blas", "blaaaass");
    auto vv = std::vector<std::string>{"bla", "blas", "blaass"};
    std::string goo = std::format(
        "Show me the keys: {}",
        join(vv, ",")
    );
    std::cout << goo << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems you should use `std::array` instead of tuple in your tuple-case.

Comment: I have tried , but that wont work either.. if i simply change the return of get:
return std::array< std::common_type_t<KEYS...> , sizeof...(keys)>{keys...};

the operand complains about the type being const char*

Comment: Because `const char*` is not a range, you should return `std::array< std::string, sizeof...(keys)>{args...}` or the something like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tuples aren't ranges. A range, in C++ terms, requires that all elements of the range are of the same type. Tuples aren't like that, so they cannot be manipulated by any range mechanisms.